Trying to remember name of a movie in which a Swiss bank employee helps the lead character escape from pursuers
I had thought this was from a Bourne move, but having just watched the trilogy again, I must have got confused.
Trying to identify an action movie (possibly in the Bourne style). The key bit I can remember is the character makes it to a private Swiss bank with just an account number for a secure safety deposit box. I can't remember exactly what the characters find in the box there, but they are being pursued by Police at the time.
A bank employee helps them get out of the bank undetected, claiming it is a special service for account holders. They go through a tunnel to where a bank armoured car is waiting. The bank employee drives them past a Police roadblock - officers stop him, since he is wearing a Rolex, which seems out of place for a someone claiming to be an ordinary driver. The bank employee claims the watch is a fake, and they manage to evade the police, although the lead character is double-crossed by the bank employee in the end.
Possibly a heist movie?

"The Da Vinci Code"
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382625/
Jürgen Prochnow plays the driver with the Rolex.
You can watch the movie here in crap quality, and ca. at the 1:14:40 mark you can see the scene with Prochnow as the driver, and with the Rolex:



A French policeman/agent stops the car, but Prochnow manages to trick/fool the policeman. Ca. at the 1:15:16 mark start the sequence where the French agent notices the Rolex on the driver's wrist. 

Yes!  That was it. That has been bugging me all day. Thank you :-)

Incidentally, what the hell is with that youtube link? Are they trying to hide the movie from youtube's copyrighted material detection?

No problem. Please mark the answer above as Best Answer. Thank you.

Yeah, I think that is the reason movies are uploaded distorted, in crap quality. That way there is a better chance that the movie will not be deleted due to copyright reasons.
